# Rabin-Miller in Java

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I got a function RSA program using BigInteger class.
However I generated my primes using the built in function. Instead, im asked to generate two primes, p and q via a Rabin-Miller test

The rabin-miller will run separately, I will generate two primes then enter them as static numbers in my RSA program, so they will be 2 separate programs.

The pseudo code for [rabin-miller on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class MillerRabin {

    private static final BigInteger ZERO = BigInteger.ZERO;
    private static final BigInteger ONE = BigInteger.ONE;
    private static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    private static final BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");

    public static boolean isProbablePrime(BigInteger n, int k) {
        if (n.compareTo(ONE) == 0)
            return false;
        if (n.compareTo(THREE) < 0)
            return true;
        int s = 0;
        BigInteger d = n.subtract(ONE);
        while (d.mod(TWO).equals(ZERO)) {
            s++;
            d = d.divide(TWO);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            BigInteger a = uniformRandom(TWO, n.subtract(ONE));
            BigInteger x = a.modPow(d, n);
            if (x.equals(ONE) || x.equals(n.subtract(ONE)))
                continue;
            int r = 0;
            for (; r < s; r++) {
                x = x.modPow(TWO, n);
                if (x.equals(ONE))
                    return false;
                if (x.equals(n.subtract(ONE)))
                    break;
            }
            if (r == s) // None of the steps made x equal n-1.
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static BigInteger uniformRandom(BigInteger bottom, BigInteger top) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        BigInteger res;
        do {
            res = new BigInteger(top.bitLength(), rnd);
        } while (res.compareTo(bottom) < 0 || res.compareTo(top) > 0);
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // run with -ea to enable assertions
        String[] primes = {"1", "3", "3613", "7297",
                "226673591177742970257407", "2932031007403"};
        String[] nonPrimes = {"3341", "2932021007403",
                "226673591177742970257405"};
        int k = 40;
        for (String p : primes)
            assert isProbablePrime(new BigInteger(p), k);
        for (String n : nonPrimes)
            assert !isProbablePrime(new BigInteger(n), k);


    }
}
```

**Now my questions:**

Out of this I will have to generate x number of primes, out of x number bitlength.
So lets say: generate 2 prime numbers out of 512 bits. Any idea how this could be done?

Also im supposed to generate 20 random a.

I guess I dont need the ending of the program or the code with top bottom
Just the mathetatical operations that represents rabin-miller and then somehow produce primes out of X bitlength

How would I do this?

Comment: I don't understand what is confusing you. You want a 512 bit prime, so pick random 512 bit integers and test them with Rabin-Miller.

Comment: yes but how?  First of all, I dont need the uniformRandom for this code to work? I can just put the math in the main methode? I just started working with BigInteger class, never seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you want to have a big integer in the range `2 ^ 511` to `2 ^ 512 - 1`. That way you can be sure that the initial bit is set to one, making it a 512 bit random number. It may be kind of strange, but a 512 bit random number only contains 511 random bits; obviously the first bit cannot be zero because in that case the number is not 512 bits in size.

So to do this you need to generate a number between `0` and `2 ^ 511 - 1`, then add `2 ^ 511` to it. Of course you want to use `SecureRandom` for secure key generation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int bitsize = 512;
    SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        BigInteger randomForBitSize = createRandomForBitSize(bitsize, rng);
        System.out.printf("%d : %X%n", randomForBitSize.bitLength(), randomForBitSize);
    }
}

private static BigInteger createRandomForBitSize(int bitsize, Random rng) {
    BigInteger randomFromZero = new BigInteger(bitsize - 1, rng);
    BigInteger lowestNumberBitSize = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(bitsize - 1);
    BigInteger randomBitSize = lowestNumberBitSize.add(randomFromZero);
    return randomBitSize;
}
```

Comment: It may be faster to use a byte array of 64 bytes, fill it with random bits and then set the most significant bit (of the first byte) to 1 using OR : `| 0x80`, then use `new BigInteger(1, byteArray)` to create the integer.

Comment: It is also faster to calculate 2^n like this: `BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(n)`

Comment: @Henry A million runs indeed shows a difference: the `pow` function takes 137 ms while the optimized, less readable shift operation takes 113 ms (for the million runs in total!). Personally I don't give a darn about the difference, but a hell of a lot about readability. Especially if you think about the fact that the random number generation will be *much much much* slower anyway; that's why I was trying to optimize that.

Comment: I checked the source code for `BigInteger.pow()` and powers of 2 in the base are special-cased to use left shifts anyway!

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's not that surprising, isn't it? Makes me have to remember one less hack. Same for generating random bits, there is a check if the requested maximum is precisely 2^n, because then you just need to generate bits and use the result as a number. No need for rejection sampling.